# iOS: Fetching CNContact Using Identifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cncontact

I'm having trouble refetching a `CNContact` using an identifier. Early on I enumerate through all contacts and do something with the phone Numbers, while storing the identifiers in an array.

Later on I'd like to fetch a specific contact using one of the stored identifiers using the following (where `currentIdentifier` is the identifier I stored earlier):

```
CNContact *currentContact = [[CNContact alloc] init];
currentContact = [self.contactStore unifiedContactWithIdentifier:currentIdentifier keysToFetch:@[[CNContactFormatter descriptorForRequiredKeysForStyle:CNContactFormatterStyleFullName]] error:&error];
```

However, I keep getting `NULL` when I log it.

Comment: When you get `NULL`, what is `error`?

Comment: If I log out `currentContact` it logs `(NULL)`. Same thing when I log out the `error`.

Comment: Why are you initializing an object with `CNContact *currentContact = [[CNContact alloc] init];` when you're overwriting it with the next statement? Have you intialized `error` to `nil`? Break the 2nd statement into 3 single statements. What do you get?

Comment: have you found solution to this? kind of having the same problem right now.